# Trouble getting a modular Zend Framework project started

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

I'm trying to set up a modular Zend Framework project with frontend and backend modules, but I just can't get it working. When I visit my `public` directory in a web browser, I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception'
>   with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954):
>   Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
>   Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97):
>   Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Application.php(366):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #3
>   /Users/Martin/Dropbox/Repositories/realestatecms/public/index.php(25):
>   Zend_Application->run() #4 {main} Next exception
>   'Zend_Controller_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified
>   (error)#0
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954):
>   Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
>   Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) in
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php
>   on line 336

I have created the two modules using the Zend Framework command line tool, and those two `module` directories have `Bootstrap.php` with two classes in called `Frontend_Bootstrap` and `Backend_Bootstrap` respectively.

My `application.ini` file looks as follows:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/frontend/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
...
```

What have I done wrong? How do I get my `Frontend_IndexController()` to run when I visit http://example.com/public in my browser?

**EDIT:** If I update my configuration file with the lines as per Ivan's answer, I now get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Resource_Exception'
>   with message 'Bootstrap file found for module "default" but bootstrap
>   class "Default_Bootstrap" not found' in
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Modules.php:83
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(683):
>   Zend_Application_Resource_Modules->init() #1
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(626):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('modules')
>
> ## 2 /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586):
>
> Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #3
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Application.php(355):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL) #4
>   /Users/Martin/Dropbox/Repositories/realestatecms/public/index.php(25):
>   Zend_Application->bootstrap() #5 {main} thrown in
>   /usr/share/ZendFrameworkCli/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Modules.php
>   on line 83

Where is it getting `Default_Bootstrap` from as a class name?!

Comment: in /modules/default/Bootstrap.php check bootstrap class name. Logic for modules bootstraps is in `Zend_Application_Resource_Modules::init()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found the solution on this page:
http://updel.com/zend-framework-modular-application/

You have to comment the following line in /MyApp/application/configs/application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

like this:

```
;resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

It fixed the problem, unfortunately I am not skilled enough to explain/understand why, sorry.  :-)

I hope it helps though.

Answer (score 0):

did you change this line:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/frontend/controllers"
```

I think it should be like this:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

Then if you need other default module/controller than index/index use these configuration options:

```
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "frontend"
```

And you shouldnt access http://yoursite.com/public. It will raise error. Public directory should be your web DocumentRoot and you would access it like this: http://yoursite.com/

Comment: Hi Ivan. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've updated my original post with the new error message I'm getting now.

Comment: I never changed default values. I prefer routes for such tasks.

Comment: make sure that in your module directory you have all modules: frontend, backend and default directories, and appropriate bootstrap class for default module: "Default_Bootstrap"

Answer (score 0):

Martin, when you call *http://example.com/public* Zend Framework will throw the error you saw because the router is looking for a *controller* named *public*. 
The normal way to view the a Zend Frame work web site is to call *http://example.com* or *http://example.com/index.php*.
 All requests to the application are routed through  */application/public/index.php*.

It looks like your original configuration for:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/frontend/controllers"
```

was likely correct for your application.

These are the typical lines in the *application.ini* for enabling modules

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""//Frontend may be your default
resources.modules = ""
```

you may have some differences depending on structure.
Also it is usually helpful for each module directory to include it's own *bootstrap.php* that extends *Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap*

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {
    //put your code here
}
```

If this doesn't help fix your problem please include your directory structure and your application.ini(you can leave out db settings and such), Index.php would be helpful if it has been changed from default. 
Also please include your version of Zend Framework.